# How do I read last n characters of a string in a single file?

Tags: c, arrays, char, fgets

I want to read the last n characters of a line in the file "passwordhashes.txt". If "$1$$" is detected in a line, I want to print the last 26 characters of that line and if "$6$$" is detected instead, I want to print the last 90 characters of that line. The following code returns the first 26 characters if md5 is detected and first 90 characters if sha512 is detected but that is not what I want.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>

int printDataError()
{      
  printf("Data error: Invalid entry found (Skipped)\n");
}    

int main(void)
{
  char buf[1024];
  char **arr2 = NULL;
  int size2 = 0;
  FILE *f2;
  f2 = fopen("passwordhashes.txt", "r");

  while(fgets(buf, 1024, f2)) {
    size2++;
    arr2 = realloc(arr2, sizeof(char*) * size2);
    arr2[size2 - 1] = strdup(buf);
  }

  char line[1000];
  char hash[1000];      
  char md5[5]= "$1$$";
  char sha512[5]="$6$$";
  char *ret;
  char *ret2;

  // Read file line by line     
  for(int j = 0; j < size2; j++) {      
    memset(hash, '\0', sizeof(hash));
    strcpy(line, arr2[j]);

    // Search for md5 
    md5[4]='\0';
    ret = strstr(line, md5);

    // Search for sha512
    sha512[4]='\0';
    ret2 = strstr(line, sha512);

    if (ret) {
      strncpy(hash, line,26);     
      printf("Line %d hash: %s\n", j+1,hash);
    } else if (ret2) {
      strncpy(hash, line,90);    
      printf("Line %d hash: %s\n", j+1,hash);    
    } else {
      printDataError();
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

A few lines in the passwordhashes.txt (there are a total of 219128 lines in this file so I will just list out a few):

```
a:$1$$Ij31LCAysPM23KuPlm1wA/
a:$6$$ek/ucQg0IM8SQLyD2D66mpoW0vAF26eA0/pqoN95V.F0nZh1IFuENNo0OikacRkDBk5frNqziMYMdVVrQ0o.51
aah:$1$$bh5o1cAKfH43fc/B1.AjF0
aah:$6$$jdxDww2LkNSlQPmWe5iDRAoBBT5IXa9241nN2bcm2Aukdrr4iH27Y6dj801MjLFaDQxbDBNxY4jvlXdIemiCY/
aahed:$1$$zA2Ef92JR9W7kqAf8Km5B0
aahed:$6$$mYQU7f3NL9Dysccvwv2BAyiCb/gxh9lN1gGnC9sa2uwHGX9VVb7jp3b7u/EZbdObqWrRFgiOLcRn7PEW1cOcz.
aahing:$1$$lDHqezDzqgN4GXlWys7LB0
aahing:$6$$rqJD4oAdyTJ3EasAFN.FeNwTFiCIIklFEo2YcxSS1X5Vutrlqu7r91c4G0PnsVAISIUIBX9.d.8riuVMmKddy/
```

Comment: What is the problem?  You read whole lines and save them.  You can search for your patterns; if you find one, you can find the length of the line, subtract the appropriate length, and voila — your data.  So, what's the issue?

Comment: Given `char md5[5]= "$1$$";`, the assignment `md5[4]='\0';` is peculiar — not harmful, but not necessary either.  Similarly for `sha512`.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler How do I find the length of the line and subtract it?

Comment: Length?  `strlen()`?  So, copy from `&line[strlen(line) - 26]` (±1), etc.  Check that the line is long enough before trying it, though; you'll crash if the line is shorter than you think it should be.

Comment: It also looks, from your sample data, as if the last 26/90 characters are the characters after the `$n$$` marker; it isn't clear you have to do more than add 4 to the value from `strstr()` to find the start of the hash data.  Given that you're using `fgets()` — a reasonable decision — you probably need to worry about removing the newline it reads and preserves.

Comment: Tangentially, it is not a particularly good idea to increment your `arr2` array of pointers by 1 at a time for 219k lines.  You end up with quadratic behaviour as the previous pointers are copied around.  You're interleaving `strdup()` calls which probably wrecks your chances of getting contiguous data, so you have maximum memory fragmentation this way.  A standard trick is to double the size of the array when you run out of space.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple remake of `strncpy` which is a standard function which copies n characters from a source to a destination.
This function copies `n` characters from the last from `src` and copy it to `dest`. if `n` is greater than the length of `src` , it does nothing.

```
#include <string.h>
void strlncpy(char *dest , char *src , size_t n){
    size_t len = 0;
    if(!dest || !src || (len = strlen(src)) < n)
            return;
    char *p = src + (len - n);
    strcpy(dest , p);
}
```

Here is a remake of your program using `strlncpy`,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define DELIM ':'
#define MD5_SIGN "$1$$"
#define SHA512_SIGN "$6$$"
#define MD5_LEN 22 /* I changed this to get only the hash. */
#define SHA512_LEN 86

void strlncpy(char *dest , const char *src , size_t n){
    size_t len = 0;
    if(!dest || !src || (len = strlen(src)) < n)
            return;
    char *p = src + (len - n);
    strcpy(dest , p);
}

int main(){
ssize_t r = 0;
size_t n =0;
char *o = NULL , *p  = NULL , hash[100];
FILE *fp = NULL;
if((fp = fopen("passwordhash.txt", "r")) == NULL){
    printf("cannot open file!\n");
    return -1;
}
while((r = getline(&o , &n , fp)) != -1){
        p = o;
        /* Print the raw text. */
        printf("RAW TEXT:: ");
        while(*p != DELIM){
                putchar(*p);
                ++p;
        }
        putchar('\n');
        p = o; 
        if(strstr(p , MD5_SIGN)){
                /* plus one is for the newline. */
                strlncpy(hash , p , MD5_LEN + 1);
                hash[strlen(hash)-1] = '\0'; /* remove newline. */
                printf("MD5 HASH:: %s\n" , hash); 
        }else if(strstr(p , SHA512_SIGN)){
                strlncpy(hash , p , SHA512_LEN + 1);
                hash[strlen(hash)-1] = '\0'; 
                printf("SHA512 HASH:: %s\n" , hash);
        }
}
fclose(fp); // Also close files!
return 0;
}
```